# How to write custom TFS work item workflow transition action?

Tags: c#, tfs, workflow

I'd like to modify our TFS (2013 Update 4) work item workflow so that when a bug transitions from Proposed to Active, a new child development Task is created to record the actual work on, and a testing task to record the test activity/results. But I can't find a good reference for how to write a custom action. I assume it involves writing code (not just some XML "instructions") to define the action. Any pointers and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is undocumented.

You can achieve your objective, using a serverside plugin that triggers after a workitem is changed. You can the new version of [TFS Aggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/releases) or write your own.